# REGEX: Get double (positive or negative) from string

Tags: java, regex

I`ve been trying to extract doubles (positive or negative) from a string with regex patterns, but the one that works better just gets the positive ones.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
```

This is Java code.

Here`s an example of what I`m trying to work with:

https://www.google.es/maps/dir/6.1521026,-75.6158273/6.1769038,-75.5853826/6.150728,-75.5312788/6.2007872,-75.5786226/6.236831,-75.5706288/6.1868153,-75.5914233/6.1742041,-75.3394911/6.2646443,-75.5684491/6.2541748,-75.4211777/@6.2402553,-75.6186275,11z/data=!3m1!4b1

Do you now how to add negative doubles to the ecuation?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesnt work :/

If I trow this:

https://www.google.es/maps/dir/6.1521026,-75.6158273/6.1769038,-75.5853826/6.150728,-75.5312788/6.2007872,-75.5786226/6.236831,-75.5706288/6.1868153,-75.5914233/6.1742041,-75.3394911/6.2646443,-75.5684491/6.2541748,-75.4211777/@6.2402553,-75.6186275,11z/data=!3m1!4b1

Result with the one that im using:
6.1521026
75.6158273
6.1769038
75.5853826
6.150728
75.5312788
6.2007872
75.5786226
6.236831
75.5706288

Result with that one:
null
null
null
...

Comment: [Check this demo with `-?\\d+\\.\\d+` as regex](https://regex101.com/r/YO7v0m/1)